# How to add template to child from ts code using ElementRef in angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs-scope

Lets say i have a component `app` and a component `child`, in App Component template i have the ability to use
`<child-template></child-template>` and its working just fine.

I have another js data table add on that creating a table, i would like to find element in the table and use `ElementRef.nativeElement` in order to add the  dynamicly from the typescript code. is it possible by someway?

something like:

```
element = $(this.el.nativeElement.children[0]);
element.parent().find(".dt-toolbar").child( ---> <child-template> / new ChildComponent()<-----)
```

Comment: Is this what you're looking for: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-component-loader.html?

Comment: @Sasxa do you know if the part of  <template ad-host></template> can be added dynamically to a dom object and then load dynamicly the component?   something like  element.parent().find(".dt-toolbar").append('<template ad-host></template>') when clicking a button and then load the component dynamically?

Comment: I didn't try, so not sure. Anyway why add it dynamically? Template tag doesn't render on the client, and isn't it easier to just add it to your `dt-toolbar` component?

Comment: The problem is that dt-toolbar been generate by running datatable(). So it not possible at add it in the template..